# How to play youtube videos inside iPhone app from the video url?

Tags: iphone

I am working on a project where I have to play some videos in my iPhone app. Is there any way so that I can play the videos directly using youtube video URL? I have to use lots of videos and I don't want to save them in my local iphone database. I am very new to this field.

In my project there will be a list of cancer disease. I mean blood cancer, bladder cancer, brain cancer etc. If a user clicks a particular cancer disease, then there should be a video regarding that cancer in the next view. I want to play that video directly (or something like that) using url. It should be like youtube video (streaming video). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed many times on SO. Alternatively, theres an Open Source Project allowing this, that I recommend:

https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

Comment: This is going very complex...I have not understand anything. Please help me with simple code. I am very new to this field...Thanks

Comment: It would've been more help if you listed some of those SO posts.

Comment: And project is discontinued. Author points to the following library instead: https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController

Answer (score 1):

Add following frameworks: a) AVFoundation b) MediaPlayer

and write these import statements :

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> 
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

and then write code whenever you want

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

[moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: sorry..sir....its working...actually video is appearing very late in my iphone simulator. What is the reason of issue (very slow)????

Comment: almost 8/10 minutes take to appear the video...my net is very slow. that may the reason?...One more thing--when i used your link (http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov) its working fine. How can I use a particular video (that I want) from YouTube. I have open a video from youtube and copied that link but it was not coming. So please tell me how can I use video url from youtube.